# Builtin run keyword with named dict as argument

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework, keyword-argument

The requirement is to run a Robot keyword which has named arg as dictionary, from PYTHON
But when we call like below, what i expect is a dictionary for arg1 and a string 'hello' in arg2, when calling "Test KW", but i get is, whole dictionary in arg1, and arg2 as empty

Need your help. Below is the minimal working code

**cat testcase.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library    /homes/user/importresource.py

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    custom keyword
```

**cat test.robot**

```
*** Keywords ***
Test KW
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}=     ${arg2}=

    ${newvr}=  set variable   ${arg1}
    ${type value}=    Evaluate     type($arg1)
    Log To Console     ${type value}

    Log to console    ${arg2}

    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{arg1.keys()}
    \    Set To Dictionary    ${args}
    ...    ${key}=${arg1["${key}"]}
```

**cat importresource.py**

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class importresource(object):

    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 3
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def custom_keyword(self):
        BuiltIn().import_resource('/homes/user/test.robot')
        args = {'arg1':{'key':'value'},'arg2':'hello'}
        BuiltIn().run_keyword('Test KW',args)
```

Comment: Your `args` variable is already a dictionary. For some reason you are then converting it into a list of strings and then passing it into the function as individual strings. Essentially doing extra work to turn it into the wrong thing. Why not just pass `args` in directly?

Comment: suppling the args directly will not help if there are two argument needed. For eg.Test KW
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}=    ${arg2}= 

And if my input is args = {'arg1':{'key':'value'},'arg2':1}
Always the arg1 will be having the full dictionary..

arg2 will be empty.. so the items are converted to string list and unpacked for run_keyword

Comment: unpacking  args dictionary with **, also doesnt help, due to the exception
Exception: run_keyword() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg1'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of this pseudocode.

Comment: Minimal reproducible example is added now.. what i expect is a dictionary for arg1 and  a string 'hello' in arg2, when calling "Test KW", but i get is, whole dictionary in arg1, and arg2 as empty

Comment: @BryanOakley do you have any clue on this behavior?